# UPS Address Street Level Validation

Tags: c#, ups

This may be a very generalized question but had anyone has much luck with utilizing the UPS Street-level validation API?  I have studied portions of this:  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Benz_CPE.aspx?msg=3658759&display=Mobile

And this:
https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit/downloadresource?loc=en_US

UPS has not been very helpful with their own sample code.  Even after obtaining an access key, their sample insists sample data (even with the test-environment-acceptable states) that the state provided is invalid.  Looking for more leads.

Comment: I am sure you will get better responses if you try some code yourself and end up in some error and post your code and error details here.

Comment: All I did was rewrite the portion to make the call and wrap up other things inside of a separate class that basically uses the other 95% of UPS's code base. but it would be helpful if you gave some example data so we can analyse it and see whats up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPS informed me that the C# sample is configured for "Urbanization" which is only appropriate in Puerto Rico.  I modified the code as follows:

```
class XAVWSClient
{
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
        XAVService xavSvc = new XAVService();
        XAVRequest xavRequest = new XAVRequest();
        UPSSecurity upss = new UPSSecurity();
UPSSecurityServiceAccessToken upssSvcAccessToken = new UPSSecurityServiceAccessToken();
        upssSvcAccessToken.AccessLicenseNumber = ;
        upss.ServiceAccessToken = upssSvcAccessToken;
        UPSSecurityUsernameToken upssUsrNameToken = new UPSSecurityUsernameToken();
        upssUsrNameToken.Username = ;
        upssUsrNameToken.Password = ;
        upss.UsernameToken = upssUsrNameToken;
        xavSvc.UPSSecurityValue = upss;
        RequestType request = new RequestType();

        //Below code contains dummy data for reference. Please update as required.
        String[] requestOption = { "1" };
        request.RequestOption = requestOption;
        xavRequest.Request = request;
        AddressKeyFormatType addressKeyFormat = new AddressKeyFormatType();
        String[] addressLine = { "3930 KRISTI COURT" };
        addressKeyFormat.AddressLine = addressLine;
        addressKeyFormat.PoliticalDivision2 = "SACRAMENTO";
        addressKeyFormat.PoliticalDivision1 = "CA";
        addressKeyFormat.PostcodePrimaryLow = "95827";
        addressKeyFormat.ConsigneeName = "Some Consignee";
        addressKeyFormat.CountryCode = "US";
        xavRequest.AddressKeyFormat = addressKeyFormat;
  System.Net.ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new    TrustAllCertificatePolicy();

        //serialize object (Debugging)
  System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new     System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(xavRequest.GetType());
        Stream stream = File.Open("SerializedXAVRequest.xml", FileMode.Create);
        x.Serialize(stream, xavRequest);

        XAVResponse xavResponse = xavSvc.ProcessXAV(xavRequest);

 Console.WriteLine("Response Status Code " +  xavResponse.Response.ResponseStatus.Code);
 Console.WriteLine("Response Status Description " + xavResponse.Response.ResponseStatus.Description);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Although I can now validate my credentials, I cannot produce multiple results and I'm not sure it's doing any validation at all considering how even if I put in a bogus address, I receive the following:

Response Status Code 1
Response Status Description Success

When I get to that point in my problem, I'll post another question.  Until then, this question is answered.

Comment: I know this is very old, but you have to use xavRequest.MaximumCandidateListSize = "5"; or whatever list size you want and then look into xavResponse. You will see a list of candidates. Try another address.

Comment: any help in this? i am looking for similar solution to pull mutiple address suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

The successful response you received is for the web service call. Now, you need to look into the possible addresses or 'CandidateType' (UPS Object).

The hierarchy response should look similar to this:

```
<soapenv:Envelop>
<soapenv:Body>
<xqv:XAVResponse>
<xav:Candidate> or <xav:NoCandidatesIndicator>
```

If you have more than one candidate address you will receive an array of Candidate Type objects. Make sure that if you only receive one Candidate Type, verify it is not a range of addresses (which is possible to get as a response if you do not include the specific number part of an address.

Hope it helps, took me a couple hours to figure this one out

Answer (score 1):

I have looked at the UPS street level API. All of my searching around didn't clarify for me where they get their data until I actually reached a developer at UPS that informed me that their data comes directly from the USPS address database augmented with a few internal metrics of their own.  Since UPS has restrictions on how you can use their data (which only allow you to ship with their service) depending on your usage volume, it might make sense to use the same USPS data but without restrictions.  This is typically available from third-party USPS data providers.  You won't be able to download a complete list of all the addresses in the country (because of privacy laws), but you will be able to use an API (without restrictions) to perform address verification.

In the interest of full disclosure, I am the founder of [SmartyStreets](http://www.smartystreets.com/), a company that does street address verification.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use http://www.verifythisaddress.com which is a WCF service that allows you to retrieve an address back from the USPS as well as over 250 countries. It is expensive though as other have stated. I have tried implementing USPS however when I entered an address of an apartment building I received a success message but it should have thrown an error that a suite range was missing. I have some hesitation on UPS validation if it doesn't validate. It defeats the purpose if you can't get the right address. Go with USPS services or a third party like the link above.